# h1:after badge not lining up properly

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a badge after the h1 on this page: `http://69.175.87.138/~plnew/portfolio-item/verde-rosa/` Unfortunately it is not lining up with the h1.  I have tried a number of things to get it to display correctly: negative margins, different `display:` values, different `line-height`s, etc.  Nothing seems to be working so I thought I would ask here.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #595959;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: "lust-display",sans-serif;
}
h1::after {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:"freight-sans-pro", lato, sans-serif;
    background-color: #C9B39E;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    content:"Marble";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="entry-title">Verde Rosa</h1>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mnzpL6/)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @j08691. I've added a JSFiddle.

Comment: Or, I guess, someone added it for me.

Comment: Just to add onto my earlier comment, make sure you post your code in your question. Sites like jsFiddle, jsbin, etc. should supplement the code in your question -- not be the sole source for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for based on the short description, but have you tried vertical-align?

```
h1::after {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "freight-sans-pro", lato, sans-serif;
  background-color: #C9B39E;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  content: "Marble";
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @Marc beat me to it by a few seconds!

Comment: Huh, for some reason I thought that `vertical-align: middle` only worked on  things that were set to `display: table-cell`?  Thanks!  Works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `vertical-align: middle` to the `:after` pseudo-element.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #595959;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: "lust-display", sans-serif;
}
h1::after {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "freight-sans-pro", lato, sans-serif;
  background-color: #C9B39E;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  content: "Marble";
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="entry-title">Verde Rosa</h1>
```

Comment: Heh, you posted this literally as I was moving my mouse to the "Post Your Answer" button -_-

Comment: @TylerH These things tend to happen, I got lucky today!